# What meaning could possibly $m\simeq_{prim}n$ have?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

For positive integers, what does $m\simeq_{prim}n$ means? I have this:

Let $\alpha\in\mathbb Z \wedge n\;$ positive integer.

If $\alpha\simeq_{prim}n$, then $\alpha^{-1}\equiv\alpha^{\varphi(n)-1}$(mod $n$).

How could this make sense?

Edit: $\varphi$ is Eulers totient function.

Comment: I guess, it would mean *coprime*.

Comment: @Berci: Thanks! It seems to be correct then, is it deep/known?

Comment: @Lehs: I have never seen this symbol in my life. Usually one says "$n,m$ are coprime", or "$(n,m)=1$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the context, it seems this notations $\ a\simeq_{prim}b\ $ wants to mean that $a$ and $b$ are *coprimes*, i.e. don't share any common prime divisor.

Then, the statement is simply another form of [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), as we have
$$1\equiv a^{\varphi(n)}=a\cdot a^{\varphi(n)-1} \pmod n,$$
so the multiplicative inverse of $a$ exists and is $a^{\varphi(n)-1}$ modulo $n$, whenever $a$ is coprime to $n$.

Comment: That does indeed seem to be the case. Which makes it a truly horrible notation (since it looks like it should be an equivalence relation).